# Trying To Sort A List Of Dicts After Combining Django Query

Tags: python, django

I have a django view that I need to query from different models and combine them, and then organize by date ('created_at'), right now when combining the models I get a list of dicts like below.  How can I sort this by date.

```
[{'content': u'Just another another message', 'created_at': 
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 15, 35, 11, 577175, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
u'successmatch_id': 5, u'id': 8, 'reciever': u'UserA'}, 
{'content': u'testing blah', 'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 
22, 15, 33, 28, 84469, tzinfo=<UTC>), u'successmatch_id': 5, u'id': 7, 
'reciever': u'UserB'}, {'content': u'Hi how are you', 
'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 13, 29, 49, 516701, 
tzinfo=<UTC>), u'successmatch_id': 5, u'id': 6, 'reciever': 
u'UserA'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's built-in sorting has the ability to specify what metric to sort by:

```
x = [{"test": 1}, {"test": 2}, {"test": 0}]
x.sort(key=lambda item: item["test"])
```

`x` is edited in place, and is now:

```
[{'test': 0}, {'test': 1}, {'test': 2}]
```

So, in your case, assuming your list is called `my_list`, you'd want to do:

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda item: item["created_at"])
```

Or, if you wanted the newest dicts to occur first,

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda item: item["created_at"], reverse=True)
```

Comment: yea thats what i figured but for some reason I get none

Comment: @R.J.Jackson `list.sort` edits the list in-place, so you **shouldn't** do `my_list = my_list.sort()`.  All you need to do is `my_list.sort()`.  Alternatively, if you want it to make a new list, you could do `new_list = sorted(my_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, you can use `pandas`, which accepts a list of dictionaries.

But note that `datetime` objects may be converted to `pandas.Timestamp` objects.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

lst = [{'content': u'Just another another message',
        'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 15, 35, 11, 577175, tzinfo=None), 
        u'successmatch_id': 5, u'id': 8, 'reciever': u'UserA'}, 
        {'content': u'testing blah',
         'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 15, 33, 28, 84469, tzinfo=None),
         u'successmatch_id': 5, u'id': 7, 'reciever': u'UserB'},
       {'content': u'Hi how are you', 
        'created_at': datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 22, 13, 29, 49, 516701, tzinfo=None),
        u'successmatch_id': 5, u'id': 6, 'reciever': u'UserA'}]

res = pd.DataFrame(lst).sort_values('created_at').T.to_dict().values()
```

Result:

```
dict_values([{'content': 'Hi how are you', 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-04-22 13:29:49.516701'),
              'id': 6, 'reciever': 'UserA', 'successmatch_id': 5},
             {'content': 'testing blah', 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-04-22 15:33:28.084469'),
              'id': 7, 'reciever': 'UserB', 'successmatch_id': 5},
             {'content': 'Just another another message', 'created_at': Timestamp('2018-04-22 15:35:11.577175'),
              'id': 8, 'reciever': 'UserA', 'successmatch_id': 5}])
```